# iMessage and FaceTime from complete stranger

Tags: messages, facetime

I have had the same problem as the previous complainant. I received an iMessage from a @yahoo.com address saying "hi". I then asked who this was and the reason for the message and also how he obtained my number and email. He claimed that he has me stored in his directory as "Abba". I'm certainly no Abba!

I asked him to remove me from his contacts, to which he agreed. Today the idiot messages me again saying hi. I mentioned that I would have him reported, he then called on FaceTime and hung up???? Also sent me a pic of himself!! How do I block him from contacting me, this is rather annoying?

Answer (score 7):

First, the best advice for dealing with a hungry [troll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll_%28Internet%29): *don't feed him*.

**Ignore this guy, and he will quickly get bored and move on.**

If your device runs iOS 7, you can block FaceTime and messages from known addresses that disturb you.

However, if unknown individuals are bothering you with frequent iMessage text messages, you can adjust your Notification settings to ensure that you are not interrupted with alerts when messages from unknown contacts are received (the messages will still be waiting for you in the Messages app, but you will not receive pop-up or banner notifications about them).

To disable notifications for iMessages from unknown contacts, go to the *Settings* app, then *Notifications*, then *Messages*, then scroll down to the "Show iMessage Alerts From" and select *My Contacts Only*.

Then, ensure that the person who is harassing you via iMessages is NOT in your Contacts.  You should no longer receive alerts about his messages (but they will still be received in the Messages app).

Note that this **also** means that you will not receive notifications about messages received from ANY unknown contacts - you will only receive notifications about messages received from phone numbers or email addresses that are stored in your Contacts.  So, be sure to check your Messages app regularly to see if you've received any messages from people not in your Contacts list that you WANT to hear from.

Comment: This is a good, comprehensive answer. If things got bad enough, you could consider disabling iMessage, and then contacting your service provider to see if they have the ability to block certain phone numbers from calling or SMS your number. They may not have an option, but it's possible. You could then disable MMS, as well, to prohibit you from getting the pictures. Note that doing that would effectively cut off your reception of *any* text-style photos which may not be worth it to you.

Answer (score 5):

Just as anyone can dial a phone number, whether you have it unlisted or they don't know who you are - anyone can face time or message whatever address or phone number they care to.

With telephones you can block things from the phone company as their software is programed to allow this. With iOS 7, it also can be programmed to block calls from a caller that you don't want to hear from again.

From the settings app, use Message or FaceTime preferences to add numbers to a your devices block list.

[image: iOS 7 call blocking settings]

Answer (score 3):

Here is my story.  I have been facetiming my elderly mother nightly for a long time.   I call my mother on her iPad through her email.  When we upgraded to iOS 7 we started to have trouble, she said she was not receiving my calls.  Finally last night some random (and angry) woman answered my FaceTime call and told me not to call her anymore. It looks like FaceTime on occasion is  connecting people to the wrong number or email address.  Seeing I'm on the calling side,rather than the recieving side, of this issue, it is not malishish, it is a technical problem that Apple needs to fix.

Comment: This is good information - not always are calls intentionally misdirected - it could be a glitch in the routing system.

Answer (score 1):

This has been happening to me a lot.  I get a FaceTime call from someone. I decline it because I don't accept FaceTime calls from people I don't know. But this one was insistent so I called it back, prefixing the number with #31# (I am in Australia on Telstra so that's the prefix they supply to block caller-id - see http://exchange.telstra.com.au/2012/06/19/how-to-block-your-number-when-calling-someone/) and spoke to the guy.  It turns out he's not a troll or spammer, but just a guy who thought he was FaceTimeing his wife and kids. I got him to try again, checking the number first and confirming it was nothing at all like my own number, and sure enough, his call came through to me, and his wife.  When his wife answered it showed up on my phone as "answered on another device".  So somehow his wife's number has become associated with my Apple Id.

It's possible that his wife used to have my number, as per this https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6259693?tstart=0 (my number is only about 4 years old) but we checked that and he claimed that was not the case. However he's not called me back since so perhaps he checked and then went and cleaned out his old contacts.

Just today I got another such FaceTime call from another weird number. I guess it's the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Call your phone company or go on their site and have that number/email blocked. I know verizon has a blocking option right on their website. You will have to log on to your account to do so.

Comment: I'm not so certain that the carrier can block FaceTime or iMessage calls since that is a data service through Apple. Thankfully, iOS 7 has blocking.