# How to stop FaceTime and iMessage alert

Tags: iphone, ios, facetime

I have a data only sim which has poor signal at home. Every time my phone loses signal and gets signal again it displays this message.

> Möglicherweise fallen vom Netzbetreiber SMS-Gebühren beim Aktivieren
> von FaceTime und iMessage an.

which translates to

```
Your operator may incur SMS charges when you enable FaceTime and iMessage.
```

If I leave my phone for a long time it connects to the network maybe 30 times then I have 30 alerts to dismiss before I can use my phone.

I really don’t want to change my number as I’m only using a data only sim while in another country.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you lose your cell connection, and reconnect again, Facetime / iMessage may need to verify if your cellular network has changed and thus the SMS request pop-ups. (Nobody at Apple must have thought of your scenario of frequent disconnection as that is rare).

See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/390578/333666) for a short term solution - and contact Apple support and report your issue so that they can hopefully fix it.

Comment: What is the difference between "losing your cell connection, and reconnecting" and "turning a phone off and on again" (or even activating/deactivation airplane mode)? One doesn't get a message then.

Comment: @nohillside I guess when your turn on Airplane mode, ios knows you have turned it on and that it is a deliberate action by you. But when you restart your mobile phone, or it gets disconnected because of poor signal, iOS is not sure why it happened and assumes that perhaps you have changed your cellular network and / or SIM card, and thus tries to verify it.

Comment: I don't remember ever getting the message after restarting the phone.

Comment: @nohillside With some cellular providers (especially in US) Apple has an understanding for activating Messages / Facetime and not charging for the SMS sent.  So iOS maybe sending the SMS in the background for you. I have received this message numerous times in the past with older versions of iOS. Since I have disabled associating my phone number with iMessage / Facetime, I can't verify if this expensive 'irritation' on restarts still persists on new iOS.

Comment: I'm in Switzerland :-) I'm not doubting that something is triggering these SMS, but loss of signal alone doesn't seem to be enough (disabling Wi-Fi and then physically removing/reinserting the SIM card doesn't trigger it).

Comment: It may be because it is a data only SIM - no phone number therefore no real SMS. I've never tried swapping SIMs to go abroad, I always just roam my usual SIM, mainly because of the EU's 'flat rate' rule no matter which country you're in; I too have never seen this message, no matter where in the EU I've travelled.

Comment: You don’t like micro cells to fix this?

Comment: @bmike I thought it should be a separate answer on its own.

Comment: @Tetsujin That's strange as whenever my relatives travel abroad, they are unable to send or receive any iMessages until they sign-off from iMessage and restart and sign-in again. It's supposed to be a security feature as Apple detects change in geography. If you don't experience it, perhaps Apple has an understanding with some of the carriers in EU too. I am in India, and even if I travel to the middle-east, I have to do the above steps to reactivate my iMessage.

Comment: I've not travelled outside the EU since the very early days of iPhones 10 years ago, before the equal tariffs were introduced, so I used to switch off roaming entirely to prevent the then ludicrous charges.

Comment: @nohillside Here's a list of [carriers world-wide with whom Apple has some tie-up](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204042) on some of its features. Note that if a carrier is not listed, it doesn't mean that the feature won't work - I am on a carrier that is not listed here, but nearly all the features work.